# Document is being deleted after updating lucene.net

Tags: .net, .net-core, lucene.net

I am using lucene.net 4.8.0 beta version in my .net core project.i want to update a document but after updating the document is being deleted from index this is my code:

```
var d = new Document()
        {
              new TextField("like_count", newValue.ToString(), Field.Store.YES)
        };
        using (var _directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "LuceneData"))))
        {
            var config = new IndexWriterConfig(version, _analyzer);
            IndexWriter _writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, config);
    
            Term term = new Term("Id", placeid.ToString());
            _writer.UpdateDocument(term, d);
            _writer.Commit();
            _writer.Dispose();
        }
```

thanks for consideration